# How to reset auto increment column of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have a table and it's first column `sl` is auto incrementing. After populating my table, I removed first two rows, and the first entry is having `sl` 1. Is it possible to reset it to 1 maintaining AI? I am using PHP MyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i got your question but if you want your column `sl` to be renumbered do `ALTER TABLE your_table DROP sl` and then `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD sl your_definitions`

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reset the auto-number back to `1` you can use either:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tablename, RESEED, 0)
```

or

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

The first option will simply reset your `auto-number counter` while the second will clear your table of all data and reset the counter.

Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=0;`. The next record will be entered with index 1.