# How to reseed an "Auto increment" column for InnoDB engine database?

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I am using an *artificial primary key* for a table. The table had two columns, one is the `primary key` and the other one is a `Dates` (`datatype: Date`) column. When I tried to load bulk data from a file (which contained values for the second column only), the `YYYY` part of the dates were added to the primary key column (which was the first column in the table) and the rest of the date was truncated.

*So I needed to reset the table*. I tried it using the `Truncate table` statement, but it failed with an **error** because **this table was referenced in the foreign key constraint of another table**. So I had to do it using the `delete * from table;` statement. I did delete all the records, but then when I inserted the records again (using the insert into statement this time), it started incrementing the ID starting from the year after the last year in the year I had previously inserted (i.e. *it did not refresh it*).

**NOTE:- I am using MySQL 5.5 and InnoDB engine.**

**MY EFFORT SO FAR:-**

- I tried `ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;` ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753511/how-to-reset-auto-increment-column-of-a-table-in-mysql) Second Answer) --->  IT DID NOT HELP.
- I tried ALTER TABLE table1 DROP column; ([Reference-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753511/how-to-reset-auto-increment-column-of-a-table-in-mysql) answer 1) ---> `Error on rename of table1`
- Deleted the table again and tried to do:

  ```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT('table1', RESEED, 0);
  ```

  ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472578/dbcc-checkident-sets-identity-to-0)) ---> `Syntax error at "DDBC"` - `Unexpected INDENT_QUOTED`
  (This statement is right after the delete table statement, if that
  matters)
- In [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/delete-all-data-mysql/) article, under the section named "*Auto Increment Columns for INNODB Tables*" and the heading "Update 17 Feb 2009:", it says that *in InnoDB truncate does reset the AUTO_INCREMENT index in versions higher than MySQL 4.1*... So I want some way to truncate my table, or do something else to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT index.

**QUESTION:-**

**Is there a way to somehow reset the auto_increment when I delete the data in my table?
I need a way to fix the aforementioned DDBC CHECKINDENT error, or somehow truncate the table which has been referenced in a foreign key constraint of another table.**

Comment: Not your question but you can insert the `(id, dates)` pairs instead of the `(dates)`. This way, you can assign id values manually.

Comment: Does disabling the foreign keys allow you to run a `truncate`? (and then of course re-enable them afterwards)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Thank you for saying that, because I have a question: I have an autoincrement index on ID, and I wonder when I am inserting all the values for the ID myself, what is the point of having an auto_increment? Does Load DATA INFILE not work when it comes to auto-incrementing the column which has been indexed so? I'll be grateful if you can clarify me on that.

Comment: @Zarah `auto_increment` is mere convenience. Think of a column with the `default` option. You can leave out the value for this column and the default value is used instead. `auto_increment` columns act similar except that that an increasing value is used. (`auto_increment` is not "smart" as in searches the first free value but rather uses 1 + $theLastValueUsedByAutoIncrement (if I am not mistaken)).

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann What's "$" in "1 + $theLastValueUsedByAutoIncrement"?

Comment: @Zarah the `$` was pseudo code. I wanted to say that the next auto increment value will be one plus the last used auto increment value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below steps:

Step1: Truncate table after disabling foreign key constraint and then again enable-

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
truncate table mytable;
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Step2: Now at the time of bulk uploading select columns in table only those are in your csv file means un-check rest one (auto id also) and make sure that colums in csv should be in same order as in your table. Also autoid columns should not in your csv file.

---

You can use below command to upload data.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE mytable fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (field2,field3,field5);
```

Note: If you are working in windows environment then change accordinglyl.

Comment: Have you checked that this does in fact reset the auto increment counter?

Comment: Truncate always reset the counter..your problem is how can truncate the table..so you can do it by this.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Thank you very much! I did this and this solved the problem. I will need a bit of more information about checking and unchecking the columns for bulk load. How do you check (or select) and uncheck the columns at the time of bulk loading? Is there a command?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes, exactly this one had solved my problem. It was first suggested by a_horse_with_no_name in the comments of the question.

Comment: @Zarah if you are using any GUI tool like sqlyog then you can do it simply checking and unchecking box during uploading data..and if you want to do it through command then use command in my answer..

Answer (score 4):

You can only reset the auto increment value to 1 (not 0). Therefore, unless I am mistaken you are looking for

```
alter table a auto_increment = 1;
```

You can [query the *next* used auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table) value using

```
select auto_increment from information_schema.tables where 
  table_name='a' and table_schema=schema();
```

(Do not forget to replace `'a'` with the actual name of your table).

You can play around with a test database (it is likely that your MySQL installation already has a database called `test`, otherwise create it using `create database test;`)

```
use test;
create table a (id int primary key auto_increment, x int); -- auto_increment = 1
insert into a (x) values (1), (42), (43), (12);            -- auto_increment = 5
delete from a where id > 1;                                -- auto_increment = 5
alter table a auto_increment = 2;                          -- auto_increment = 2  
delete from a;
alter table a auto_increment = 1;                          -- auto_increment = 1
```

Comment: I had tried this statement, but had set auto_increment to 0.